# CHANGE event not firing from Numeric Stepper (AS3, Flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a [`NumericStepper`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/NumericStepper.html) and I've registered it with a [`CHANGE`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/NumericStepper.html#event:change) event.

```
import fl.controls.NumericStepper;
var myNumericStepper:NumericStepper = new NumericStepper();
myNumericStepper.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, function(e:Event):void {
    trace("changed");
});
```

Whenever I *"click"* on the plus or minus buttons, my event handler will be triggered as expected. However, when I change the `value` programmatically, the handler doesn't get fired!

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    myNumericStepper.value = 7;
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To work around the issue, try to dispatch the `CHANGE` event manually:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    myNumericStepper.value = 7;
    myNumericStepper.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
});
```